# How can I change the title of a ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was looking [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes) but I can't figure it out.

How can I change the word "type" to something else?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Add

```
+ labs(colour = "legend title")
```

to your ggplot call.
Great resource site is also [google group for ggplot2](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/).

**edit**: this assumes that colour is the aesthetic in the legend, e.g. `qplot(x,y,colour=z)`.  If another aesthetic is being shown in the legend, use that as the argument instead, e.g. `+ labs(fill = "legend title")` for a raster/image plot.

More generally, if you specify an explicit scale such as `scale_colour_continuous`, you can set the `scale_name` argument (*warning*: the details of the arguments to scales may have changed in recent releases of `ggplot2`; this description is of version 0.9.2.1).

Comment: Thank you Roman!! Could you also tell me how I could change the text for "A" and "B"?

Comment: @brani - The answer depends on where "A" and "B" are in your plot. Are they values that get plotted? An axis label? Assuming they are values that are plotted on the x-axis, you could do something like this `scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("a", "q", "z"), labels = c("foo", "bar", "baz"))` to change the labels for the values a, q, and z. You could also address the issue outside of ggplot before you plot. If "A" and "B" are an axis label, `xlab("pink monkeys")` or `ylab("aardvarks are angry")` should do the trick.

Comment: @Chase They are the levels of the factor that define the color of the points (see the link).

Comment: I often use this site (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) too. It provides many examples of how to use ggplot2.

Comment: @Roman: If you have something like: `ggplot(aes(..., colour=g, lty=g, groups=g))` then your answer doesn't work. Instead, it creates an additional legend.

Comment: I thought that either "color" or "colour" could be used, but it seems that in this case that "colour" has to be used as the keyword

Comment: @Mark, yeah, very counter-intuitive and user-unfriendly... =/

Comment: @aL3xa only for the non-American speaking world. :)

Comment: Yeah, but why for the love of god `color` doesn't do the same thing? It's not about promoting British English, it's about consistency. If I put `color` in `aes` mappings, I should refer to that esthetic layer with eponymous argument. Strange...

Comment: The answer to the deleted question (posed as an answer) by @Rob is that since the legend in that example is based on the `fill` aesthetic rather than the `colour` aesthetic, you have to use `labs(fill="legend title")` rather than `labs(colour="legend title")`: this may also be relevant to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420846/how-to-manipulate-the-legend-in-ggplot

Comment: @aL3xa It's a historical accident, AFAIK. The first versions of `ggplot` only accepted English aesthetics, i.e. `colour` but not `color`. In a later version, Hadley provided duplicate arguments to `aes()`. I think you have a good case for a change request. Have you considered posting a request on the `ggplot2` issue tracker? Or better yet, submit a patch?

Comment: @Andrie, nope, neither of those two. About @hadley's coding conventions, I find Ruby-inspired-underscore-frenzy-naming-conventions by far more frustrating (yes, I'm an ESS fan). I haven't touched `ggplot2` for quite a while and, AFAICS, it underwent some (not so) substantial changes. Will have to re-catch up. Actually, I'm more prone to creating a package `unhadleyiser` to `grep` the `annoying_function_names` and `gsub` them with `proper.ones.that.i.d.like.to.use`. Surely I can rebind `_` in ESS, but where's the fun in that?! =)

Comment: @csgillespie I have the same question - in that case I find it necessary to specify both aesthetics to the same legend title in `labs(colour = "legend title", lty = "legend title", group = "legend title")`. Is there an easier/neater/better way?

Answer (score 9):

Add either:

```
+ scale_fill_discrete(name="Title", labels=c("1","2","3"))
```

or

```
+ scale_colour_discrete(name="Title", labels=c("1","2","3"))
```

depending on the geom.

I recommend you look into the ggplot2 cheatsheet. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 5):

None of the others worked for me for some reason.  In case they failed for you as well, adding this worked for me:

```
+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title='MY NEW TITLE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a word to the wise ... all of these options above can be overridden if you do something dumb like I just did.  Earlier in my project, I had simply turned off a legend I didn't like using the "themes" parameter within ggplot:

```
theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

If you do this, no matter what beautiful commands you put in to change the title -- and I tried all of those above -- they won't be overridden by your command to turn the legend off!  You have been warned!  ;{)