# How to change the title of Y axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this:

```
      test_data <- data.frame(
      var0 = 100 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -20, 20))),
      var1 = 150 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
      date = seq.Date(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100))
```

To plot both time series var0 and var1 on the same graph, with date on the x-axis, using ggplot2

```
             ggplot(test_data, aes(date)) + 
             geom_line(aes(y = var0, colour = "var0")) + 
             geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1"))
```

This will work fine and plot two time series in different colors but the title of Y axis and the legend will be"var0".

- How to change the title of Y axis and the legend to,for example,variable , value
- how to change the colors of both var0 and var1 lines

Thanks

Comment: All your questions have been already answered on stackoverflow, for example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438752/adding-x-and-y-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171263/r-changing-line-colors-with-ggplot) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911567/how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-ggplot2-legend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(date)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = var0, colour = "var0")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour = "var1")) +
scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","yellow"), name="Experimental Condition", labels=c("Var 1", "Var 2")) +
ylab("Var X")
```

Comment: no worries, add argument `size=2` (2 being an example) to the `geom_line` function.